# Ajax load select option Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm still new in javascript and ajax, i'm trying to create ajax show current category on my html select in my CodeIgniter project, the code is below:

Here's HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category" onclick="loadCategory();">
   <option value="">Choose</option>
   <option>&nbsp;</option>
   <option>&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

Here's Javascript:

```
function loadCategory()
{
 var url = "<?php echo site_url('home/ajax_show_category_options');?>";
 $('#category').load(url);
 return false;
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function ajax_show_category_options()
  {
    $category = $this->db->get('category')->result();
    $data = "<option value=''>-- Choose--</option>";
    foreach ($category as $rowCategory) {
      $data .= "<option value='".$rowCategory->id."'>".$rowCategory->name."</option>";
    }
    echo $data;
  }
```

When i clicked select option, will execute loadCategory() and then append the select with current category list. The question is after i choose the category, the select option will running loadCategory() over again and the value option that i choose will be empty. How to stop loadCategory() after i choose option? Thanks.

Comment: don't use click listener on a `<select>`. Will fire when you open the select and when you select an option. listen for change event

Comment: So, what should i do?

Comment: onchange will only fire when options are selected/deselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep this simple, **Set a global boolean variable**. Set it's value to `true` and check if it is true before performing `ajax call`. Consider below example.

```
var loadedOptions=false;//global variable
function loadCategory()
{
    if(!loadedOptions){
       var url = "<?php echo site_url('home/ajax_show_category_options');?>";
       $('#category').load(url,function(){
           loadedOptions=true; //set it to true once request is done
       });
    }
    return false;
}
```

<strike>Furthermore, you can also try unbinding `click event` on `select element` with `off` [Check for the usage of `off` based on `jquery` version you are using].</strike>

**For ex**

```
function loadCategory()
{
    var url = "<?php echo site_url('home/ajax_show_category_options');?>";
    $('#category').load(url,function(){
           $("#category").off('click');
    });

    return false;
}
```

---

Try using `removeAttr` to remove `onclick` from `select element` as below:

```
$('#category').load(url,function(){
   $("#category").removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

Comment: It's give me empty select when i clicked select option in the first time

Comment: Did you set it `loadedOptions` variable to `false` globally?

Comment: Yes, i do. It's give me like disabled option. So i try to use onchange after onclick in id="category". Still same result.

Comment: `off()` won't do anything when inline `onclick` is used

Comment: I think what i want is when I choose a category then don't loadCategory() anymore and made the value of category i choose is still there.